# I want to know explanation that playframework scala sample code of zentask

Tags: playframework-2.2, scala-2.10

I have problems understanding this piece of code:

```
Project.scala

def index = IsAuthenticated { username => _ =>
    User.findByEmail(username).map { user =>
      Ok(
        html.dashboard(
          Project.findInvolving(username), 
          Task.findTodoInvolving(username), 
          user
        )
      )
    }.getOrElse(Forbidden)
  }

Application.scala trait Secured

def IsAuthenticated(f: => String => Request[AnyContent] => Result) = Security.Authenticated(username, onUnauthorized) { user =>
    Action(request => f(user)(request))
}
```

How is "IsAuthenticated" function mapping parameter?

```
user => _ => User.findByEmail..{...}
              how mapping?
f: => String => Request[AnyContent] => Result
```

It would be kind if you could explain me this code in depth. Thank you in advance :)